# Updated XCode from 7.1.1 to 7.2 causes warnings and build errors

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I updated my XCode to 7.2 yesterday from 7.1.1 in order to have the new iOS 9.2 SDK. I didn't make any changes; still I got one warning stating this:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/andre/Privat/Prosjekter/Swift/my-app/My-app/build/Debug-iphoneos'
```

Long text:

```
Ld /Users/andre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-app-fqeokpwxllwqeughpoprzldbnhiu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/My-app.app/My-app normal x86_64
    cd /Users/andre/Privat/Prosjekter/Swift/My-app/My-app
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
-arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk
-L/Users/andre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-app-fqeokpwxllwqeughpoprzldbnhiu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/andre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-app-fqeokpwxllwqeughpoprzldbnhiu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/andre/Privat/Prosjekter/Swift/My-app/My-app/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks
-F/Users/andre/Privat/Prosjekter/Swift/My-app/My-app/build/Debug-iphoneos
-filelist /Users/andre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-app-fqeokpwxllwqeughpoprzldbnhiu/Build/Intermediates/My-app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/My-app.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/My-app.LinkFileList
-Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -Xlinker
-objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lc++ -licucore -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreText -framework GLKit -framework GoogleMaps -framework ImageIO
-framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework youtube_ios_player_helper -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
-Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/andre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-app-fqeokpwxllwqeughpoprzldbnhiu/Build/Intermediates/My-app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/My-app.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Wax_room.swiftmodule
-framework AddressBook -framework MapKit -framework CoreLocation -framework Pods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/andre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-app-fqeokpwxllwqeughpoprzldbnhiu/Build/Intermediates/My-app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/My-app.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/My-app_dependency_info.dat
-o /Users/andre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-app-fqeokpwxllwqeughpoprzldbnhiu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/My-app.app/My-app
```

What is wrong? I don't understand the error message.

Comment: Clear the DerivedData folder and try

Answer (score 3):

This is quite a common problem, I'm afraid. If you've already tried cleaning your project using Shift+Alt+Cmd+K and restarting Xcode, you might need to do the following:

- Go to your project in the navigator pane (the bit on the left) then choose your target.
- Click on the Build Settings tab.
- Search for "Library" until you find Library Search Paths, then delete whatever you see there. Same goes for the Framework Search Paths. *Lovely.*

Now try again.

**Update**: See Michaël's comment below that you should check the frameworks path too – hurray for Xcode's almost impenetrable build system! :)

Comment: I think the issue is concerning frameworks paths because of the `-F` argument. Thanks for the shortcut by the way ;)

Comment: I use that shortcut so often I had to stop and think what the keys actually were. Muscle memory! :)

Comment: I don't understand a bit of this. Why it happened or what the error is. It worked after removing "Pods_My_App" from the "Link Binary With Libraries" under Build phases after I reverted the project file.

Comment: I'm afraid it's difficult to know what might have caused such a specific problem; Xcode can be awfully opaque sometimes. If my answer helped you, would you kindly mark it as correct so others can find it more easily? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem yesterday and I solved it by removing and adding new scheme. 
Here is how: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeManage.html).